# KOtlin Coroutine with MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Iam  extremely new to kotlin, this is my first kotlin MVVM app, actually app is not running, help me to find what is the mistake i made here.

LoginViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel (private val loginRepository: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {
     suspend fun login(email: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {

                val loginModel = LoginModel(email, password)
                val response = loginRepository.getUsers(loginModel)
                Resource.success(data = response)

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Resource.error(data = null, message = ex.message ?: "Error occured!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

API Helper:

```
class ApiHelper (private val api: Api) {

    suspend fun makeLogin() = api.makeLogin()
}
```

ViewModelFactory:

```
class ViewModelFactory (private val apiHelper: ApiHelper) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(LoginViewModel::class.java)) {
            return LoginViewModel(LoginRepository(apiHelper)) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class name")
    }
```

Model class:

```
data class LoginResponse(
    val token : String
)
```

Model class

```
data class LoginError(
    val error: String
)
```

Repository:

```
class LoginRepository(private val apiHelper: ApiHelper) {

    suspend fun getUsers(loginModel: LoginModel) = apiHelper.makeLogin()
}
```

API:

```
interface Api {

    @POST("login")
    suspend fun makeLogin(): Response<LoginResponse>
```

Help me, Because i'm a beginner, i referred so many tutorials, but i didn't understand.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow

Comment: hello sir, iam just a beginner, can u help me @user3159253 ?

Comment: Hi your question is unclear  also please check your activity have you used view model instance in that (in case you are not able to install the app please check logcat first)

Comment: pls check what is the error in my code @R

Comment: Would you like an example project from Github?

Comment: yes, i need @RishabhKumarSingh

Comment: [WordList](https://github.com/amanr11314/WordList) is a simple project which uses MVVM architecture. Further, if you want [Sangeet](https://github.com/Chandigarh-University-students/Music-Player) is a bigger project (a music player) which uses MVVM architecture.

Comment: i need a simple login program @RishabhKumarSingh

Comment: @user15272114 Can you please elaborate on how do you want to make login system? You want to use room database or Firebase auth system?

Comment: Post
request
{
    "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
    "password": "cityslicka"
}
response:
{
    "token": "QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4"
}        simply i need to call this using kotlin MVVM @RishabhKumarSingh

Comment: @RishabhKumarSingh sir,

Comment: Can you show what error are you getting?

Comment: Sir, it is not working. my task is while iam click on the login button, if the email and password is correct, then it show a toast "QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4"(response) @RishabhKumarSingh

Answer (score 0):

I think your viewmodel is not initialized.
Use updated libraries for initializing viewmodel in activity and fragment

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extension:2.2.0" //for Activty
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0' // for fragment
```

intialized loginViewmodel in activity like this below.

```
val loginViewmodel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()
```

Get the instance of same loginviewmodel in fragment like this below

```
val loginViewmodel: LoginViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

create method in viewmodel to get the instance of LoginRepository like this below

```
fun setLoginRepository(loginRepository: LoginRepository){
        this.loginRepository = loginRepository
    }
```

No need to pass repository object into constractor of viewmodel in your case and initialized repo object inside activity or viewmodel its your choice. Rest of your code looks fine. It might be helpful to you. If you need any other help let me .